# Haskell how to add instance that can handle List of Maybe

Tags: haskell

I haven't found any good examples of this kind of situations.

I have this kind of datatypes and a class with instances:

```
data Type1 = Const1 | Const2
 deriving Show
data Type2 = Type2 Int 
 deriving Show
 
class Class a where
 function :: a -> Int
 
instance Class Type1 where
 function Const1 = 2
 function Const2 = 3
 
instance Class Type2 where
 function (Type2 x) = x * 2
```

Should add instances that can compute this way:

function [Just (Const2), Nothing, Just (Const1)]

function [Nothing, Nothing, Just (Type2 1), Just (Type2 2)]

Is there a way to do this something like this?

```
instance Class (Maybe a) where
 function Nothing = 0
 function (Just x) = function x <--- gives an error
 
instance Class [a] where
 function [] = 0
 function [x] = function x <--- error
 function (x:sx) = function x + function xs <--- error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say this:

```
instance Class a => Class (Maybe a) where ....
```

and likewise

```
instance Class a => Class [a] where ...
```

This means that `Maybe a` is only an instance if `a` is, and likewise for `[a]`. This in turn lets you use `function a` in the implementations.

Answer (score 3):

This only works if `a` is a member of the `Class` typeclass, so you need to add that as a constraint:

```
--           ↓ add a typeconstraint
instance Class a => Class (Maybe a) where
    function Nothing = 0
    function (Just x) = function x

--           ↓ add a typeconstraint
instance Class a => Class [a] where
    function [] = 0
    function [x] = function x
    function (x:xs) = function x + function xs
```

Indeed, you write for example `function (Just x) = function x`, but that only works if `function x` makes sense, and that is the case of `a` (the type wrapped by `Maybe`), is an instance of the `Class` typeclass.

We then can determine the `function` of the sample lists:

```
Prelude> function [Just (Const2), Nothing, Just (Const1)]
5
Prelude> function [Nothing, Nothing, Just (Type2 1), Just (Type2 2)]
6
```